# Calculating difference between two UML models

Tags: java, uml

I would like to know some references and ideas in how to calculate the (set?) difference between two UML models. Basically, I have a system (represented in UML/xmi), and to this system several patterns (also represented in UML/xmi) can be applied.

For example, we can apply pattern a to the result of applying pattern b to the system - `Pa(Pb(S))`. I would like then to calculate `dif(Pb, S)` and then `dif(Pa, S)`, since after a pattern is applyed, the merged system can be considered as a original system.

I'm looking for references (in the literature or not) and algorithms, since I dont want to reinvent the wheel. I will code in Java in the end.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Eclipse EMF Compare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/), you can compare two different EMF model instances. Since UML is represented as an EMF Model instance in Eclipse, you can use it to compare your UML models. Just install EMF Compare, mark your UML models in the package explorer (or whatever view you use) and the choose Compare -> With each other... from the context menu. The Compare editor will let you save the differences as an .emfdiff file.

Comment: This looks interesting, but my intention is to compare any two uml models, and not compare against itself in the version control. At least, I understood the EMF Compare as this, I'm still looking in the documentation if it is possible to compare arbitrary models.

Comment: @PedroDusso No, it's not a comparison to itself. You can compare any two EMF model instances with each other and therefore you can also use any UML model instances.

Comment: yes, you are right! But I cant make the "Each other" option available, and the tutorials are not helping. I have to work with an EMF Project in order to achieve this?

Comment: @PedroDusso No, it doesn't need to be an EMF Project. You just need to have the right plugins installed. Maybe the Eclipse forums will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm marking it as answer. However, EMFCompare handle *.xmi files, and I have as input a *.uml file. I believe that internally the uml file is a xmi. Do you know if it can be passed as a parameter without any kind of casting? I will post this on Eclipse foruns as well, thanks again!

Comment: @PedroDusso that doesn't matter because the .uml file will be loaded to an UML EMF model instance in memory. It is just the a different type of persistent resource. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 2):

I can't point you to exact literature, but if you don't/can't go for the EMF solution above, think about this:
UML models are graphs (I takes some thinking to figure out what the edges and vertices are, but anyway). To get the difference you need the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of both the vertex and the edge sets. That way you get everything that is in only one of the graphs. If you compute the symmetric difference between the original and the model with the applied pattern, that will give you exactly what the pattern did to the model.

Comment: This looks really interesting, I should think about how to effectively represent the model in order to execute a algorithm to code this difference